# How to add dynamic multiselect list in drop down. I want dynamic. when I will add some new value in the table then it will come in drop down

Tags: magento2

form.php file (but my code is static i want dynamic)

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'billingcycle',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'label' => __('Select Billing Cycle'),
                'title' => __('Select Billing Cycle'),
                'name' => 'billingcycle[]',
                'required' => true,
                // 'values' => $this->_options->getOptionsArray(),
                // // 'class' => 'billing',
                'values' => [
                    ["value" => "Once a day","label" => __("Once a day")],
                    ["value" => "Once a week","label" => __("Once a week")],
                    ["value" => "Once a month","label" => __("Once a month")],
                    ["value" => "Once a year","label" => __("Once a year")],
                ],
            ]

        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add configuration in which you can add dynamic values like https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/dynamic-row-system-config.html

and then call this config and show every value that is in this config. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add to Your Form.php

```
protected $_options;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Status $options,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_options = $options;
    ...
}


    $fieldset->addField(
        'billingcycle',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'label' => __('Select Billing Cycle'),
            'title' => __('Select Billing Cycle'),
            'name' => 'billingcycle[]',
            'required' => true,
            'values' => $this->_options->toOptionArray(),
        ]

    );
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**Status.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Status implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * Get Grid row status type labels array.
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        /*$options = ['Pendding' => __(' Please Select '),'Enable' => __('Enabled'),'Disabled' => __('Disabled')];*/
        $options = ['Enable' => __('Enabled'),'Disabled' => __('Disabled')];
        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * Get Grid row status labels array with empty value for option element.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $res = $this->getOptions();
        array_unshift($res, ['value' => '', 'label' => '']);
        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * Get Grid row type array for option element.
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($this->getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $res[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }
        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getOptions();
    }
}
```